# KIE-WB REST API Deployments

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, kie, kie-wb

I want to know if its possible to attain a process id using a deployments id (or any way for that matter) assuming no processes have been started. i.e none exist in the database.

I am trying to create a dynamic list that contains all deployments currently active, and then when it is clicked on a new process instance can be started.

Is this possible? or am I reaching for the stars :P

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check how is this done inside the jbpm console ng Deployment Unit list. Which basically contains all the deployments. The process definition list is just showing the sum of all the processes inside the deployments.

HTH

Comment: I'm trying to use rest to get all process definitions currently active, as I need the id from them along with deploymentId so I can start a process form...

Comment: Look for a deployment service in the rest endpoints you should be able to get all the deployment ids first and then get all the process definitions for each of them.

Comment: what is the rest call for that? I have looked over the api over and over but cant find anything that will give me a processId...  Assume no instances have been created and its just a deployment and process definition that exist. hopefully that helps show what im doing haha